# Get-ADGroupMember processing for non domain members

Tags: powershell, active-directory

We have a trusted domain that we administer and users are given acceess to a file server on our domain through groups on the trusted domain added to the local domain group which controls permissions e.g.

For the path "\server\folder\folder" the permissions might look like

```
MyDomain\FolderXReadWrite
```

Then **within** that group a group from the trusted domain would be included

```
TrustedDomain\FolderXReadWrite
```

I'd like to write a script to "reverse engineer" this so that I can derive both the local and trusted domain groups that have access from a given folder path and list them - I've got the following:

```
$path = '\\server\path\path'

$Permissions = (Get-Item -Path $path -ErrorAction Stop | Get-Acl -ErrorAction Stop).Access | Where-Object { $_.IdentityReference -like "MyDomain\*" } | ForEach-Object {
    $TrustedDomGroup = Get-ADGroupMember ($_.IdentityReference.Value -split '\\')[1] -Verbose | Where-Object { ($_.DistinguishedName -split 'DC=', 2)[-1] -like "*TrustedDomain*" -and ($_.objectClass -eq 'group') }
        If ($TrustedDomGroup) {
            [pscustomobject]@{Name=("TrustedDomain\" + $TrustedDomGroup.SamAccountName);Rights=("Member of " + $_.IdentityReference);Domain='PHS'}
        }
        [pscustomobject]@{Name=$_.IdentityReference;Rights=$_.FileSystemRights;Domain='NSS'}
    }

$Permissions | Sort-Object Name -Unique
```

This produces the output I require, however, the domain group in the above example has LOTS of users therefore processing "Get-ADGroupMember" takes a long time. Does anyone have suggestions for a faster method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the best method to improve the lookup speed seems to be using LDAP so I put together a small function to get Foreign Security Principal group names from a local AD group:

```
Function List-FSPGroupMembers {
# Use LDAP search to find and resolve Foreign Security Principals from an AD group - faster than native cmdlet
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=1)][string]$GroupName="",
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=2)][string]$Domain
    )
    [regex]$SIDmatch = "S-\d-(?:\d+-){1,14}\d+"
    Function fGetADGroupObjectFromName([System.String]$sGroupName,[System.String]$sLDAPSearchRoot) {
        $oADRoot = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry($sLDAPSearchRoot)
        $sSearchStr ="(&(objectCategory=group)(name="+$sGroupName+"))"
        $oSearch=New-Object directoryservices.DirectorySearcher($oADRoot,$sSearchStr)
        $oFindResult=$oSearch.FindAll()
        If($oFindResult.Count -eq 1) {
            Return($oFindResult)
        }
        Else{
            Return($false)
        }
    }
    $sSearchRoot="LDAP://" + $Domain + ":3268"
    If($oSearchResult=fGetADGroupObjectFromName $groupname $sSearchRoot) {
        $oGroup=New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry($oSearchResult.Path)
        $oGroup.Member | Where-Object {($_.ToString()) -match $SIDmatch } | ForEach-Object {   
            $SID = (Select-String -Pattern $SIDmatch -InputObject $_.ToString()).Matches.Value
            Try { 
                (New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($SID)).Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]).Value
            }
            Catch {
                $_
            }
        }
    }
    Else {
        Write-Warning ("Group "+$groupname+" not found at "+$domain)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to retrieve all group members with this command:

```
(Get-ADGroup $ADGroup -Properties members).members
```

I don't know if it's faster in your environment then Get-AdGroupMember.
A measurement via Measure-Command may give you more information:

[Measure-Command, Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-command?view=powershell-7)

Comment: I don't think it will be - the CN returned for members of the trusted domain are the Foreign Security Principal ones:

...so I'd have to look up them too